# Creating time sensitive URL links using Itsdangerous module

Tags: python, django

I'm using Itsdangerous module in django to create a single-use URL. It also should be time sensitve.

Reading the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/itsdangerous/), I see that there are two different classes: TimestampSigner and URLSafeSerializer. The first one creates a signature with expiration deadline. The second one works as a URL serializer, and it should be used on "environments where you only have a limited set of characters available".

There's also another class, TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer, that generates a signature which includes a timestamp (See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32763177/python-api-token-generation-with-itsdangerous)). The token it generates is not static and I can set an expiration date. However, it may be too long for the usage as an URL link.

The deal is, I'm worried about the size of the generated token, but it is a requirement that it should be unique and also expire after 1 day.

How can I do this?